# android image serialization transparent png

Tags: android, image, serialization, png, transparent

As a .net developer, new to android, I'm trying to consume images from my `asmx webservice`. Images are saved in the db as `nvarchar` (bytearray), so my webservice returns a string that can be converted into bitmap.  This all works fine but I run into problems trying to get png images with transparent parts in it.  No matter what I try, the transparent parts are always white.  The problem is, there could be a couple of things I'm doing wrong here...

This is the way I write my png to db (c#) (it could be I'm losing transparancy here already?):

```
    Image toAdd = Image.FromFile(@"I:\Andoid\h1graph.png");

    string imagestring =  System.Convert.ToBase64String(imageToByteArray(toAdd));
```

And this is the way I consume it on my android app :

```
    Bitmap bmp;

    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

    SoapPrimitive resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();

    String result = resultsRequestSOAP.toString();

    if (!result.equals("")) {

                 byte[] bloc = Base64.decode(result, Base64.DEFAULT);

                 bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bloc, 0, bloc.length);

                 bmp.setHasAlpha(true);

                 ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                 bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,  100,  os);

                 byte[] bloc2 = os.toByteArray();

                 Bitmap bPNGCompress =  BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bloc2, 0, bloc2.length);

                 viewModel.setThreeD(bPNGCompress) ;

    }
```

I've stripped the code so only the essential code is there. So, this works but it doesn't keep transparency.

I'm guessing, it's because the `BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray` creates a bitmap without transparency, and so the rest of the conversion code won't create transparency.

I'm struggling for days now, trying to find solutions but I don't seem to find it.  There must be a best practice for consuming png images from a webservice, serialized as string (?).

Using png from the resources, works ok with transparency, so I know my png is transparent and my UI controls are ok. (I know the coding is not state of the art but to avoid having to copy paste all kinds of methods, I replaced some code, that is normally in methods, to make it more readable)

I'm at the start of a project, experimenting with android, so If anyone has a completely different idea on how te get images into my app, be free to post ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Try explicit alpha configuration for the decode operation:

`BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
opts.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;`

//and then call decodeByteArray with the explicit alpha option:

`bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bloc, 0, bloc.length, opts);`

//and then apply the same options to the compressed bmp version:

`Bitmap bPNGCompress =  BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bloc2, 0, bloc2.length);`

**Update**
I have written a simple test app to test the code and it works correctly (ie, has transparency). 
It's 100% that you lost the ALPHA bits before processing the image.

Placeholder layout:

`<ImageView
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_marginTop="135dp" />`

Code:
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

```
    byte[] imgData = Base64.decode("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", Base64.DEFAULT);
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imgData, 0, imgData.length);

    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, os);

    byte[] compressedData = os.toByteArray();

    Bitmap bPNGCompress =  BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(compressedData, 0, compressedData.length);

    imageView.setImageBitmap(bPNGCompress);`
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea but it doesn't make any difference... still no transparancy.  I'm writing a test application in .net to check if the transparancy gets lost when I add it to the db as a string, or if the problem is in the code where I consume the string in my android app.  Hopefully this will give me an idea where to look.

Comment: Yes that is correct - you lost the ALPHA(transparency) bits. I tested the above code and it works well (the answer updated too).

Comment: Thanks a lot Markus!  Now I know where to look for.  How did you create your image string, that might allso help me.

Comment: You're welcome. From Firefox or Chrome - Developer tools - Network Tab - right click on an image resource and select copy image as data URI / copy response

Comment: Ok, so the only thing left to do is to figure out how to create a string from a png that keeps the transparency in .net (can't imagine that will be difficult)  Again, thanks a lot Markus!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when transferring a png image from C# to Android. The problem turned out to be trivial. During serialization in C# I had ImageFormat.Jpg set and it should be ImageFormat.Png.

```
public static byte[] ConvertToBytes(this Image img, ImageFormat imageFormat)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        img.Save(ms, imageFormat);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
```